# Resolve a dependency on package sun.misc with Tycho

Tags: java, tycho

I try to convert a Buckminster-based build to Tycho (0.19.0). In our (mirrored) target platform we have the bundle com.lmax.disruptor from http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/ which imports the package `"sun.misc"`

When I try to build our own bundle (that depends on com.lmax.disruptor) I get:

> [ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.lmax.disruptor 3.2.0 requires
>   'package sun.misc 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I checked many Tycho tutorials but none of them contained such a dependency. Is there a way to import that package e.g., from the executing JRE?

Workaround:

When I add the disruptor bundle as a library to my bundle then it works without problems. But this seams more like a workaround because I will have other bundles that depend on it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that none of the standard OSGi execution environments exposes the package `sun.misc`, so the bundle using this package will not work on a standard OSGi runtime. This is what the build failure is telling you.

So if you had a standard OSGi runtime (note that Equinox is special here because of its [osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) option), you'd need to tell the OSGi runtime to expose additional packages from the boot class path. A way to do this (so that Tycho also understands your intention) is to build a system bundle fragment which declares an `Export-Package` of `sun.misc`.

This has been reported to work, but I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: I created a new fragment and and added this to the target platform. Afterwards the package sun.misc could be resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One way to create this fragment for consumption by Tycho is explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33379935/731040).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to include on of the pre-built system bundles provided by diffplug in your dependencies:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.diffplug.osgi/com.diffplug.osgi.extension.sun.misc/0.0.0/jar

More info at https://github.com/diffplug/osgiX