# How to verify log4j2 is logging asynchronously via LMAX disruptor?

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application and have gone to some pains to get log4j2 to work within the app. All seems to work fine now, and as a finishing touch I wanted to make [all loggers asynchronously](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#AllAsync).

I've managed to get the LMAX Disruptor on the classpath, and think I've solved the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32628098/731040) of providing `sun.misc` as well. Set the VM argument `-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector` in the run config and set up *log4j2.xml* file correctly as well. **I think**. And that's where the problem is. I'd like to be able to verify that my application logs asynchronously in the proper fashion, so I can enjoy the benefits latency-wise.

How can I - then - verify that my loggers are working asynchronously, utilising the LMAX Dirsuptor in the process?

Comment: Are you getting log output?

Comment: I do. I'm just not sure it landed there the way it should: asynchronously. And I'm past blind trust for Eclipse/OSGi black magic ;).

Comment: By the way, if you have solved the issue of providing `sun.misc` in your Eclipse plugin, would you mind answering the question you linked to?

Comment: @RemkoPopma: Will do. Still amazed I got everything to work properly, as the newbie I am.

Comment: @RemkoPopma: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33379935/731040.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two types of async logger, handled by different classes.

1. All loggers async: the `AsyncLogger` class - activated when you use `AsyncLoggerContextSelector`
2. Mixing sync with async loggers: the `AsyncLoggerConfig` class - when your configuration file has `<AsyncRoot>` or `<AsyncLogger>` elements nested in the configuration for `<Loggers>`.

In your case you are making all loggers async, so you want to put your breakpoint in `AsyncLogger#logMessage(String, Level, Marker, Message, Throwable)`.

Another way to verify is by setting `<Configuration status="trace">` at the top of your configuration file. This will output internal log4j log messages on log4j is configured. You should see something like "Starting AsyncLogger disruptor...". If you see this all loggers are async.

Comment: Setting `<Configuration status="trace">` did the trick, thanks! Should've read [the docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#StatusMessages) more carefully! After setting the config status, I get `2015-10-27 10:13:21,847 DEBUG Starting AsyncLogger disruptor with ringbuffer size 262144...`. Great!

Comment: IMPORTANT: This answer seems only partially correct. The breakpoint method works, but the `<Configuration status="trace">` method doesn't. Using the latter, I get `Starting AsyncLogger disruptor...` logs both when I specify `-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector` flag and when I don't. Using breakpoints, I see that in one case (with the flag), async loggers are indeed hit, and in the other, they aren't.

Comment: @JanŻankowski I'm seeing entirely different results when running Log4j 2.5 with Disruptor 3.3.5 in JRE 8u102.  I never see any log statements with the word "disruptor" in them.  However, if I successfully set all loggers to run asynchronously, I do see a bunch of log statements containing the text "AsyncLogger" and "AsyncContext".  In addition, removing the disruptor library causes the application to crash when trying to run all loggers asynchronously.

Comment: @RaemkoPopma Is there a way we can sync ERROR and async every other log types?

Comment: I can see the AyncLogger while using the trace and to check the async functionality I am trying to loop over the Logger.info 100000 time and in next statement after loop I am trying to create a file, but file is not created until log write completes, Am I setting wrong expectations?

Comment: Is there a way to check using the log4j API if the logging is async or what logger is being used?

Answer (score 5):

Put a breakpoint in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig#callAppenders`. Then you can watch as the event is put into the disruptor. Likewise `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig#callAppenders` should be getting hit for synchronous logging OR getting hit from the other side of the disruptor for async logging (at which point everything is synchronous again).

Comment: Would that breakpoint be called even when I configure via log4j2.xml? I've attached the sources in Eclipse and set the breakpoint, but execution doesn't stop.

Comment: It shouldn't matter I believe. Set another breakpoint in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig#callAppenders`. This should only be getting hit on the "other side" of the disruptor. If it is getting hit directly from your logger then it didn't work.

Comment: This is almost but not quite correct. The `AsyncLoggerConfig` class is not used when all loggers are async (when the `AsyncLoggerContextSelector` is configured). See my answer for more details.